# creating Debian live disk with customized gnome3 desktop

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome3, live-usb, livecd

I'm trying to make a live `Debian ISO` with `live-build`

I installed `gdm3` by installing `task-gnome-desktop`. That is the `metapackage` which I found in the live-build manual page to install all the gdm dependencies with each other.

Now I don't know how can I customize its desktop, such as enabling application menu extensions.

I tried to enable application menus in the interactive shell by trying this command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions "['apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com']"
```

I have changed the menu items by changing its desktop and directory files, but I can't make it enabled by default!

If you know any good way for customizing gnome desktop, I would love to know that cause it's awful to do all the changes in the interactive shell.

Is there any way to get the gnome desktop before creating the final `ISO`?